# How to make each row in index Dataframe have only one object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata, seaborn

I would like to create a seaborn box plot with 4 variables("Draughts",'Heating it sufficiently is too expensive',"Heating system in inadequate","Poor building fabric") and have the temperature in the y-axis. The problem is that many people surveyed more than one option per opinion. I would like to know how should I separate the options in each row while still maintaining all data.
This is some data:

```py
CausesCold                                                               
Draughts                                                             15.0
Draughts                                                             19.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive                              0.0
Draughts                                                             10.0
Draughts                                                             15.0
Draughts                                                             20.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive,Heatin...                    5.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive,Heatin...                   18.0
Heating system in inadequate,Draughts                                15.0
Heating system in inadequate,Poor building fabric                    15.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive,Heatin...                   21.0
Heating system in inadequate                                         21.0
Heating system in inadequate                                         21.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive                             10.0
Draughts                                                              0.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive,Poor b...                   18.0
Heating system in inadequate                                         18.0
Poor building fabric,Draughts                                        19.0
Heating system in inadequate,Poor building fabr...                   19.0
Heating system in inadequate                                         18.0
Heating system in inadequate                                         17.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive,Poor b...                   18.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive,Heatin...                   15.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive,Heatin...                   15.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive,Poor b...                   20.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive                             17.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive                             17.0
Heating system in inadequate                                          0.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive                             10.0
Heating it sufficiently is too expensive,Heatin...                    0.0
```

And I would like it to be like this:

```
                          CurrentThermostatTemp
CausesCold                                 
Poor building fabric                   20.0
Poor building fabric                   17.0
Poor building fabric                   20.0
Poor building fabric                   19.0
Poor building fabric                   20.0
Poor building fabric                   17.0
Poor building fabric                   18.0
Poor building fabric                   22.0
Poor building fabric                   25.0
Poor building fabric                   20.0
Poor building fabric                   15.0
Poor building fabric                   19.0
Poor building fabric                   20.0
Poor building fabric                   20.0
Poor building fabric                   20.0
Poor building fabric                   21.0
Poor building fabric                   19.0
Poor building fabric                   20.0
Poor building fabric                   18.0
Poor building fabric                   20.0
Poor building fabric                   17.0
Poor building fabric                   25.0
Poor building fabric                   18.0
Poor building fabric                   20.0
Poor building fabric                   16.0
Poor building fabric                   15.0
Poor building fabric                   21.0
Poor building fabric                   25.0
Poor building fabric                   23.0
Poor building fabric                   30.0
...                                     ...
Draughts                               20.0
Draughts                               20.0
Draughts                               17.0
Draughts                               16.0
Draughts                               25.0
Draughts                               21.0
Draughts                               21.0
Draughts                               18.0
Draughts                               20.0
Draughts                               20.0
Draughts                               18.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on how exactly your data is formatted here. Is the thermostat reading already in its own column?

In any case, you probably want to use [pandas.Series.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

something like

```
temp = data['CausesCold'].str.split(',', n = 1, expand = True)
```

This will create a new data frame with two numbered columns.

If I assume that the thermostat value is already off in in a separate column I would then merge to this "temp" data frame the thermostat values. Something like:

```
temp['thermostat']=df['thermostat']
```

Your temp df then looks something like:

```
|********************************|
|0         |1        |thermostat |
|Reason 1. |Reason 2 |Number     |
|Reason 1. |Reason 2 |Number     |
|Reason 1. |null     |Number     |
|********************************|
```

You want the 0 and 1 columns stacked with their corresponding thermostat value.

So split the df

```
df=temp[['0','thermostat']]
df1=temp[['1','thermostat']]
```

and then append them. It's also presumably the case that some people only had 1 answer (ie that column '1' is null') so go ahead and take care of that.

```
df=df.append(df1.dropna(subset=['1']))
```

If you are in the unfortunate position of having an original data source where both reasons and the thermostat code are in the same single string, I would probably as a first step do a regex extract of any digits in that string and define that as a new column called 'thermostat' or something similar.

In any case this should get you moving in the right direction. It's not necessarily the most efficient way to get there, but it will get you there.